# Accessing a model Field in admin.ModelAdmin in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

hi I want to access the value of a field in Django admin Form

model.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class MySqlQuery(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  query = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
      verbose_name = 'SQL Query'
      verbose_name_plural = 'SQL Queries'
    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

admin.py

```
 class MySqlQueryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

  list_display = ('query', 'name', 'action')

  def get_urls(self):
      urls = super(MySqlQueryAdmin, self).get_urls()
      my_urls = patterns('', url(r"^execute/$",
                       self.admin_site.admin_view(self.execute_query)))
      return my_urls + urls

  def execute_query(self, request):
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      try:
        #------------------------------------------
        #need to access query field from the models
        #------------------------------------------
        cursor.execute(self.form.query)
      except:
        logger.error('query was not right')
      finally:
        cursor.close()

      return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])

  def action(self, form):
      return "<a href='execute/'>execute</a>"

  action.allow_tags = True


 admin.site.register(MySqlQuery, MySqlQueryAdmin)
```

I have created a models.py, which have field query, i want to execute query from the Django admin. For which i need to access the field in django admin form.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't different from any other Django view. The instance of MySqlQueryAdmin doesn't refer to any instance of MySqlQuery: it's an admin for the whole model class, not any particular instance of it. That means there's no way of getting "the" value of a query instance without passing an identifier and getting the object from the database using that identifier.

```
class MySqlQueryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

  list_display = ('query', 'name', 'action')

  def get_urls(self):
      urls = super(MySqlQueryAdmin, self).get_urls()
      my_urls = patterns('', url(r"^execute/(?P<id>\d+)/$",
                       self.admin_site.admin_view(self.execute_query), name="execute"))
      return my_urls + urls

  def execute_query(self, request, id):
       query = MySqlQuery.objects.get(id=id)
       ...

  def action(self, obj):
      return "<a href='%s'>execute</a>" % reverse(admin:execute, kwargs={'id': obj.id})
  action.allow_tags = True
```

Of course, I wouldn't recommend doing anything like this at all, since you seem to be executing arbitrary user-supplied SQL against your database, but I guess you already know the risks of that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i already figured it out. Do you how to make cursor executing only read only queries?